# Функция calc() — приведение типов в CSS

Tags: css, css3

Хочу реализовать следующую задумку: в зависимости от ширины экрана генерировать цвет в `rgb()`. В данный момент есть идея использовать для этого единицы измерения `vw`, но не знаю как приводить эти единицы к пикселям, а потом получать из пикселей значения без единиц измерения.
Как это можно реализовать на чистом CSS?

```css
:root {
  --r: 100;
  --g: 150;
  --b: 200;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block {
  background-color: rgb(calc(var(--r) + 2vw), calc(var(--r) + 1vw), calc(var(--r) + 0.5vw));
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  /* doesn't work */
}
.block2 {
  background-color: rgb(calc(var(--r) + 50), calc(var(--g) + 50), calc(var(--b) + 50));
}
```

```html
<div class="block">calc() <b>not OK</b></div>
<div class="block block2">calc() <b>OK</b></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Путем чтения [документации](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-type-checking) стало понятно, что приведение типов в функции `calc()` возможно, но результат неизбежно приводится к каким-либо единицам измерения и получить просто `<number>` из, например, `<length>` нельзя, а значит заполнить `rgb()` динамически исходя из ширины экрана в `vw`-юнитах тоже нельзя.

Следующее предположение было генерировать цвет при помощи `hsl()`, ведь там в двух значениях из трех используется тип `<percentage>`, может можно как-то динамически получать проценты? Нет, проблема осталась той же, потому что математические выражения внутри `calc()` с типами `<length>` и `<percentage>` 
вначале приводятся к `<length>` и результат обязательно будет в пикселях.

> the second and third arguments of the `hsl()` function can only be expressed as `<percentage>`s. Although `calc()` productions are allowed in their place, they can only combine percentages with themselves, as in `calc(10% + 20%)`.

То есть, использовать `calc()` внутри `hsl()` можно, но только если внутри неё будут производиться операции с процентами, что никак не приближает нас к динамической генерации цвета в зависимости от ширины экрана.

Answer (score 3):

Градиентный костыль: на больших экранах синий, а на маленьких - красный. Пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/ywzd1L70/1/

```css
div {
  height: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red -10000vw, blue calc(102400px - 10000vw));
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @Vadizar, и к чему это второе двоеточие в одном предложении?

Answer (score -2):

Идея в том, чтобы определять изменения ширины на CSS можно лишь через @media. Я завязался только на популярные разрешения, но суть кажется ясна - на каждый пиксель создавать свой правило и определять переменную. Это единственное возможное решение на CSS. Хотя и бредовое:

```css
:root {
--pix: 100;
}

@media (max-width: 1680px) {
:root {
    --pix: 110;
}
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
:root {
    --pix: 120;
}
}

@media (max-width: 1170px) {
:root {
    --pix: 130;
}
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
:root {
    --pix: 140;
}
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
:root {
    --pix: 150;
}
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
:root {
    --pix: 160;
}
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
:root {
    --pix: 170;
}
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
:root {
    --pix: 180;
}
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
:root {
    --pix: 190;
}
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
:root {
    --pix: 200;
}
}

:root {
--r: 100;
--g: 150;
--b: 200;
}

.block {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid;
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
}

.block1 {
background: rgb(var(--pix), var(--pix), var(--pix));
}

.block2 {
background: rgb(var(--r), var(--g), var(--b));
}
```

```html
<div class="block block1">calc() <b>not OK</b></div>
<div class="block block2">calc() <b>OK</b></div>
```

Comment: А чего дизлайкаете? Хотели же на CSS. Это единственный вариант.

Comment: дизлайк не от меня, если что.
что касается вашего ответа, то тут нет ни функции `calc()`, ни приведения типов. идея была не в том, чтобы через медиа-запросы менять цвет, для этого даже переменные не нужны. идея создать подобие цсс-шлюза (css lock), чтобы при **каждом** изменении ширины цвет немного менялся.

Comment: Ну так добавьте calc. А идея в том, что определять изменения ширины на css можно лишь через @media. Я завязался только на популярные разрешения, но суть кажется ясна - на каждый пиксель создавать свой правило и определять переменную. Это единственное возможное решение на CSS. Хотя и бредовое.

Comment: Создавать заранее 2000 медиа-выражений тупо и для того, чтобы этого не делать, была идея воспользоваться техникой цсс-шлюзов. Повторюсь, суть вопроса не в необходимости менять цвет, суть вопроса в приведении типов в функции `calc()`.

Comment: Я согласен, что это тупо. Но вы хотели вариант на CSS.